# How to organise huge mysql database for emails and search through it

Tags: mysql, database-design

I wanted to ask you for your opinion, what would be the ultimate and the best way to store million of emails and search on them, using MySQL.

So first the product:

- You have tons of emails, which has to be stored for a very long period.
- There is an option to search on subject or content.
- You have additional flags (like tags and other small stuff)
- You have multiple users, with their own different (and multiple) accounts.

So I was wondering what would be best ?

- Create database for each and every user, and store his accounts and emails in tables in his own database
- Or create some crazy foreign key structured database (but it will be only 1 database) not 1000
- Or maybe something completely different ?

Comment: Some clarification would be very welcome - what do the words 'tons' and 'crazy' mean in this context?  Also, what is a _'foreign key structured database'_?

Comment: tons on emails would be : ~40 000 per day
  , for crazy i imagine something like a table that will contain only foreign keys of other emails, to be honest i dont know exacly. That's why I just ask for ideas. I dont mind test those ideas on my own.

Comment: how many users?

Answer (score 0):

One table, columns for `subject` and `content`, etc.  Use InnoDB on 5.6 (or later)

```
FULLTEXT(subject) -- for searching just that column
FULLTEXT(content) -- for searching just that column
FULLTEXT(subject, content) -- for searching both columns at the same time.
```

However, see the limitations on what FULLTEXT can and cannot do.